# mysql compare 2 columns in same table copy different to 3rd column

Tags: mysql

I got table called users as the following

```
New    Old   Different
Jack   Sam       Jack
smith  Smith      Anna
Sam    
Anna
```

which got  columns  new old different I need to compare between new / old if name exist in new and not in old then insert in different 
any tips for this statement

Comment: how you are arriving this row `smith  Smith      Anna` ?

Comment: Why is `Anna` added to the `Different` column for `smith`? The name doesn't exist in `New` in that row.

Comment: Jack Smith Sam and Anna all in column New , and  Sam and Smith only on Old Column , so the different column should include jack and anna

Comment: So.. why does Anna go to the smith row instead of Sam or Anna?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two queries which might do what you want - though exactly what you want is not clear (to me) from the question

One, using a "not in" condition

```
select new from users where users.new not in (select old from users where old is not null);
```

or two, using a join

```
 select users.new from users left join users as old_users on users.new=old_users.old where users_old.old is null;
```

These queries simply give you the list of "different" users. They don't insert them into anywhere, but I think your schema needs some work anyway (because I fail to see the logic of the rows in your schema).

Answer (score 0):

Best answer is to use a left join query :

```
select users.new from users left join users as old_users on users.new=old_users.old where users_old.old is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct * FROM (
  select distinct field1 as n from table
    union 
  select distinct field2 as n from table) as t;